# Postback not being triggered on Button Click when using Validators

Tags: .net, asp.net, postback

Server Click event is not being triggered when I click on the "LookupButton".  The weird part is that this code works on our Dev server, but not QA.  If I get rid of "LookupValidationGroup", from the Lookup Button ValidationGroup property, the page does postback, but then my validators do not work.  I could explicitly do the validation on the Server Side, but dont think I should need to.

No errors are being displayed.  I also reinstalled .net 3.5 using aspnet_regiis -i command.

Thanks for any help or tips provided...

```
 <table>
<tr>
    <td><label for="CRCIDTextBox">CRC ID</label> </td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="CRCIDTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="50" CssClass="RegisterInputTextBox" Columns="10"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CRCIDRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CRCIDTextBox" EnableClientScript="true"
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="CRC ID is required." ToolTip="CRC ID is required." ValidationGroup="LookupValidationGroup" 
            CssClass="ValidationError" SetFocusOnError="true">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="CRCIDRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CRCIDTextBox" EnableClientScript="true"
        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="CRC ID format is invalid. Please enter only numbers." ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ValidationGroup="LookupValidationGroup" 
        CssClass="ValidationError" SetFocusOnError="true">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>        
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="ZipTextBox">Zip Code</label></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="ZipTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="50" CssClass="RegisterInputTextBox" Columns="10"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ZipRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ZipTextBox" EnableClientScript="true"
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Zip Code is required." ToolTip="Zip Code is required." ValidationGroup="LookupValidationGroup" 
            CssClass="ValidationError" SetFocusOnError="true">      
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>        
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><asp:Button ID="LookupButton" runat="server" Text="Lookup" OnClick="LookupButton_OnClick" ValidationGroup="LookupValidationGroup" UseSubmitBehavior="true" /></td>
    <td><asp:LinkButton ID="NoSiteIDLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="NoSiteIDLinkButton_OnClick" CausesValidation="false">Do not have a CRC ID?</asp:LinkButton></td>        
</tr>
```

Comment: Just copied your code into a new website and it validates as expected, and hits the postback method if validation succeeds.  Is there anything else that might help?

Comment: That's the weird part, same code works on a different Server.

Comment: Have you tried it in alternative browsers?  Does it work in Chrome, Firefox, IE?  Does any JavaScript run successfully when browsing your QA server?

Comment: One more question - if you leave it as-is and enter some invalid data, does the validation actually show up?  Or is that broken too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the client script firing, hence preventing the post back to the server. I notice you have EnableClientScript="true" on your validators you see.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your ID="LookupButton" Button does not have CausesValidation="false".

You probably find that ID="NoSiteIDLinkButton" Button does work as it has this parameter